# Where can I find an adapter to use Breeze JS with Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rest, angularjs, breeze

I have been looking for a good REST api management adapter for AngularJS that works with my Rails backend.  I need it to be able to handle client side caching, client side lookups, and Object relational mapping (ORM).  Breeze.js looks like the right solution and they've mentioned that they were working on a Rails demo a few months ago, but I have been unable to locate it.  I've also checked out Restangular, Modelcore, and JayData, but none of them seem to have the features I need.  Has anyone:

- Used rails with breezeJS?
- Written their own adapter for BreezeJS and could advise me in writing a Rails one
- Know of an alternative solution]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great question.  We are working on a Rails adapter for Breeze but no concrete date yet for when it will be released.  The first version may be a bit anemic but we plan on improving it rapidly. Please stay tuned.

Comment: I'm willing to help out if it would speed development.  Is ther a github repo that I can look at in the meantime?

Comment: Hang in there. We should have something this week or next. It's already working ... just a matter of making it shippable

Comment: Hi Ward, any news on this adapter ?

Comment: Please see the [Breeze RoR sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/intro-spa-ruby) and tell us if it meets your needs. It's pretty simple. It doesn't try to handle OData queries and it only tolerates the saving of a single entity at a time.  These limitations are in keeping with typical RoR REST apis. W/r/t change-set saves (multiple entities saved at same time), it is possible that you'll find sufficient guidance in the code itself. Let us know :)